# ISNULL : Enhancing Performance?

Tags: sql, indexing, isnull

My query is running *s-l-o-w*.  I'm evaluating my indexes and rebuilding them, but can someone tell me if an index on MyField would be used in this query?

```
SELECT  ISNULL(MyField , 'No Data') 
FROM    MyTable
```

My thinking is:

- When SQL tests fields in an IF, WHERE or CASE it uses available indexes.
- MyField will be tested.
- Therefore, SQL should be able to use an index to test MyField.

My questions are:

- Are null values indexed?
- Does SQL use indexes if there is no IF, WHERE, CASE, etc?
- Would it make a difference if I used CASE rathar than ISNULL?

Thank you.

Scott

Comment: You've given us very little information about your particular situation. We don't know the structure or size of MyTable. And the query you are presently showing returns all rows and thus will not use an index. If you provide us more information, we may be able to explain why it's s-l-o-w.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an index will be used if one exists on that field.  The ISNULL is not relevant.

You can test this yourself as follows (turn on the query execution plan to see which index it uses:

```
BEGIN TRAN

--Create test table and add some dummy data
CREATE TABLE MyTable(MyField VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT 'test1'
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT 'test2'
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT NULL
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT 'test3'

-- Run query with ISNULL (note that a Table Scan is done)
SELECT  ISNULL(MyField , 'No Data') FROM MyTable
-- Run query without ISNULL (note that a Table Scan is done)
SELECT  MyField FROM MyTable

-- Now create an index and compare the execution plans for the same queries
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable_MyField ON MyTable (MyField) 

-- Run query with ISNULL (note that an Index Scan is done)
SELECT  ISNULL(MyField , 'No Data') FROM MyTable
-- Run query without ISNULL (note that an Index Scan is done)
SELECT  MyField FROM MyTable

ROLLBACK
```

Index scans are much faster than Table scans, so the queries after the index is created will perform better.

Comment: Brilliant.  So SQL still reads all the values, but if the field is indexed then SQL doesn't have to read them from the table, it can read them from the index instead --- is that right?

Comment: Yes, the nonclustered index is like a micro version of the table with only the data that is indexed (in this case, one column).  So the query is sifting through less data.

Answer (score 3):

just an FYI, the answer would be different if you were talking about the "Where" clause.
If you do:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(MyField , 'No Data') 
FROM    MyTable
WHERE MyField ='myvalue'
```

SQL Server will do an index SEEK (which is what you should always aim for), but if you do:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(MyField , 'No Data') 
FROM    MyTable
WHERE isNull(myColumn, 'no data') is not null  --I know this check doesn't make sense, but it's just for the sake of illustration. Imagine another function instead of isNull like substring or getdate...
```

sql server will use an index SCAN

Besides if SQL Server is using the index or not, you should ask yourself which operation it is doing on the index, seek or scan.

Answer (score 1):

Here're my idea about your questions:

<<    Are null values indexed?

Null values are indexed, as other value.

<<    Does SQL use indexes if there is no IF, WHERE, CASE, etc?

Actually, yes, because there's some method which having the same meaning with IF or CASE statement.

<<    Would it make a difference if I used CASE rathar than ISNULL?

It's the same, just different in display.

HTH.